# Error 1045 <28000>: Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, error-handling

After successfully initializing mysql, it denies access to begin the mysql command.

```
mysql -u newkelsie
```

I never recalled setting a password, but I did hit blank enter once when it asked for a password so I am not sure if that might be the problem or if I could go back and set a password. I'm using the Administrator: Command Prompt so I believe I should have all access, but instead I'm getting a common error.

```
Error 1045 <28000>: Access denied for user 'newkelsie'@'localhost' <using password: NO>
```

I've also been getting the error when I put a password in.

One of the other suggestions to answer this problem I tried was creating a document in bin called "mysql-init.txt"  It's contents include:

```
ALTER USER 'newkelsie'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'kelsie';
```

Which is supposed to set my password upon initialization. However, this is not the case. Is there a way I can get mysql running on my computer without the password?

Comment: Newer versions of MySQL assign a random root password when initialized. Look in the MySQL error log for details, it'll show you what it is there.

Comment: Simply run MySQL Installation Wizard and during repait/install process you will be prompted to enter root password